# How to Add a new compatibility mode (e.g. Windows Server 2003) to a Windows Server 2008?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server

The question is in the title.

Is it possible, and then, how? to Add a new compatibility mode in Windows Server 2008?

Thanks